# Customizing caption of listings within a beamer document

Tags: listings, captions

I want to change the font of the caption of the listings within my document.

I found the solution of doing it with the package `caption` and the tag `captionsetup`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={small,tt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, capiton=Test]
Hello World
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But I get an error

```
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
```

Thank you!

P.S.: How can I get rid of the text "Listing 1:" when I am using a caption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={small,tt},labelformat=empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, caption=Test]
Hello World
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`labelformat=empty` removes the caption prefix while `[fragile]` allows for verbatim like environments (lise `lstlisting`) to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately I still get the error `Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}` when I try to "compile" your MWE.